# mat-raised-button not working on Safari browser when using CSS Grid (Angular 6 with Angular Material)

Tags: angular, safari, angular-material

My Template Code:

```
<div>
    <div class="margin-top-title">
        <div>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div *ngIf="true">
            <div>
                <div style="height: 2000px">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <button (click)="click()">
                    Test Button
                </button>

                <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="click()">
                    Material Flat Test Button
                </button>

                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="click()">
                    Material Raised Test Button
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

My Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'testdaten',
    templateUrl: './testdaten.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testdaten.component.scss'],
})
export class TestdatenComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public click(): void {
        alert('click');
    }
}
```

As soon i need to scroll to reach the button in Safari Browser the raised-button is not working. If i click on the raised-button the Safari browser is just scroll to top. The function will not called! (Even if i use NoopAnimationsModule)
With mat-flat-button everything works fine!

Here is my Stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5f2wl-h1tz3s

Any ideas to fix that?

I'm using:

"@angular/animations": "6.1.3",

"@angular/common": "6.1.3",

"@angular/material": "~6.4.6",

**My Workaround**

grid-template-rows: $menubar-hight 1fr $footer-hight; on my app.component.html does make the problem in Safari. (I don't know why)

My Solution is using CSS switch only for Safari

```
.my-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: $menubar-hight 1fr $footer-hight;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'header' 'content' 'footer ';
}

/*Safari only override*/
@media not all and (min-resolution:0.001dpcm)
{ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
        .my-wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: $menubar-hight auto $footer-hight;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-areas: 'header' 'content' 'footer ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Safari. See your example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5f2wl

Comment: I see your stackbitz example is working. In my project, as soon i have any animations, Safari is broken. With all other browsers there are no such problems...

Comment: @MaihanNijat I also use css-grid in my project. As soon i delete display: grid it's working too... I need to verification, what's wrong...

Comment: Upload to stackblitz so I have a look.

Comment: @MaihanNijat I updated my request with a stackblitz example which is not working when using the mat-raised-button on Safari (or any other animated material component like an input). Thanks for your help!

Comment: The "grid-template-rows: $menubar-hight 1fr $footer-hight;" makes the disaster! when i use grid-template-rows: $menubar-hight 100vh $footer-hight; the button is working!